# jQuery is not working in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I want to use simplyScroll jquery in my react app. I added its CSS and jquery file in my index.html file. I also wrote below code before ending body tag but its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($){
    $(function (){
      $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

If I run `$("#scroller").simplyScroll();` in browser's console slider is working fine even if I go back and come to the current page its working.
Can someone help me on this or suggest better way to implement in react.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your script will execute **before** your React app has finished rendering. This means that your script will look for the `#scroller` node but won't find it since it has yet not been rendered by React.

The trick here is to do it **after** your React Component has finished mounting. So try this instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
}
```

Remember that you might have to install jQuery via your package manager, e.g npm or yarn. Then you also need to import jQuery to your component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

---

#### Example

Just a general example of how to integrate jQuery into your React Component. Here we add the inner text *"foo bar"* to our `#contents` div element.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    $("#contents").html("foo bar");
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="contents" />
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Now `TypeError: $(...).simplyScroll is not a function` error is coming. I already import simplyScroll in header in index.html file

Comment: you need to import it to React, not in your html header. Can you show how you do the import?